# failed to open stream : couldn't resolve host name

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

for your information i create the simple database in meta_tags.txt

Error message:

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Couldn't resolve host name in /home/myweddin/public_html/allan/header.php on line 3

Warning: fopen(http://allan.myweddingmemory.com/meta_tags.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/myweddin/public_html/allan/header.php on line 3

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/myweddin/public_html/allan/header.php on line 7

header.php:

```
<?php
$database = 'http://allan.myweddingmemory.com/meta_tags.txt';
$meta_db = fopen($database, 'r');
$page = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$page = substr($page, 1);

while($data = fgetcsv($meta_db, 9000, '|'))
{
    if($data[0] == $page)
    {
                $title = $data[1];
        $meta_keywords = $data[2];
        $meta_description = $data[3];
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php print $title; ?></title>
<meta content="index, follow" name="robots" />
```

Comment: Your first issue is that 'http://allan.myweddingmemory.com/meta_tags.txt' cannot be opened - either by your script or by me (I just entered the address into my browsers address bar and got told that allan.myweddingmemory.com could not be found).

Comment: check: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: here is the link http://allan.myweddingmemory.com/lasik/cataract/malaysia/vista/eye/specialist/reading/vistareadingfaq.php

Comment: "Couldn't resolve host name" isn't a programming problem.

Comment: second link does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: Couldn't resolve host name
```

That's your problem, right there. Your DNS resolver at the server is unable to resolve  `allan.myweddingmemory.com` to an IP address, therefore can't connect to it, therefore can't send a HTTP request, therefore can't get a response, therefore can't read its data.

Comment: thanks...i will call my hosting..

Answer (score 0):

ping your server `allan.myweddingmemory.com` and swap it out for the IP address if it returns one.
If one is not returned, then you have a problem somewhere in communication with your server.